# Convert mp4 file to tta audio through ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using the following command:

```
C:/ffmpeg/bin\ffmpeg.EXE "-i" "F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\video\ba4ca90a71e0a05f67b9274827cc4f020c6ba95d.mp4" "-q" "4" "-strict" "experimental" "-threads" "1" "-vn" "F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\audio\35b9611321a57726636a9a46c315ba395e3df6e8.tta"
```

But I am getting the error

```
    Unable to find a suitable output format for 'F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\audio\35b9611321a57726636a9a46c315ba395e3df6e8.tta'
F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\audio\35b9611321a57726636a9a46c315ba395e3df6e8.tta: Invalid argument
```

Here is the full output:

```
ffmpeg version N-77883-gd7c75a5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 25.100 /  6. 25.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\video\ba4ca90a71e0a05f67b9274827cc4f020c6ba95d.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300
  Duration: 00:00:05.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 560x320, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
[NULL @ 0000013b88e0e2c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\audio\35b9611321a57726636a9a46c315ba395e3df6e8.tta'
F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\audio\35b9611321a57726636a9a46c315ba395e3df6e8.tta: Invalid argument
```

Comment: What does `ffmpeg -h encoder=tta` output?

Comment: `Codec 'tta' is known to FFmpeg, but no encoders for it are available. FFmpeg might need to be recompiled with additional external libraries.`

Comment: What does it mean to be recompiled with additional external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
C:/ffmpeg/bin\ffmpeg.EXE -i F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\video\ba4ca90a71e0a05f67b9274827cc4f020c6ba95d.mp4" -q:a 4 -strict -experimental -threads 1 -vn "F:\laragon\www\sample\uploads\audio\35b9611321a57726636a9a46c315ba395e3df6e8.mka"
```